# Dropdown menu links from logged in user's name

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have added this code to my child theme's `functions.php`:

```
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item');
function my_custom_menu_item($items)
{
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        $user=wp_get_current_user();
        $name=$user->user_firstname; //  
        $items .= '<li><a href="">Hello, '.$name.'</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

This allows my site to display, on the menu, the first name of the user who is logged in.

However, I want users to have the ability to hover over the "Hello, [FIRST NAME HERE] and have a dropdown menu appear with options such as "My Account" and "Log out".

I have found two examples. [One is from Amazon](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1302405/cb8208653b6fe01242d899d887678ba3) (a lot more options) and the other is from Spotify (less options, and what I'm going for).

Here is the Spotify example:

[image]

What do I need to do to make this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to solve this is to use CSS to create your drop-down menu. There's a great tutorial over at W3 Schools [right here.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp)

Basically you'll give the list item you encapsulate the user's name in an ID, then set a hover trigger to that to display the menu. They're really not too complex, but it is strictly with CSS. The only thing the PHP will be doing is pulling out the user's details to help populate the links so users get to the correct areas.

Comment: I'm still learning a lot. Where would I place the CSS code in order for it to work with the logged in users First name being displayed on the menu bar?

Comment: Are you using a framework? Many frameworks have designated areas to keep your CSS organized. If you're just making your own application then you can either do inline CSS or use a CSS file and link to it within your HTML. Check out W3 schools on that as well, it's very nicely laid out.

Comment: I'm using Uncode theme http://themeforest.net/item/uncode-creative-multiuse-wordpress-theme/13373220